Does an Extraordinary Opportunity confer any net benefit?
The Bastion Events Table is used to determine events at your bastion. Essentially, this gives you a 50% chance that nothing happens. An Extraordinary Opportunity allows you to re-roll, for the significant cost of 500 gold, or do nothing.

If you seize the opportunity, you must pay 500 GP to cover costs. In return, your Bastion gains a sudden influx of recognition or attention, prompting the DM to roll again on the Bastion Events table (rerolling this result if it comes up again).


If you decline the opportunity, you don’t pay the money and nothing else happens.

Some of the events are beneficial, but some of them are detrimental. So, rolling again poses a significant cost at significant risk of detriment or gaining nothing. There is a 0.04 % chance that your bastion event yields a Rare Magic Item, and a few other more realistic benefits. But, for the most part, it would just be safer to wait for another bastion event. So, what incentive does anyone have to pay 500 gold?

It's only worth it for roleplaying reasons
I took the effort to try and calculate the expected monetary value for a roll on the event table. This is not exact science, as you have to make a couple of assumptions, for example what a use of a facility is worth on average, as you lose the use of one of your facilities in some cases.1 As this is somewhere in the 50-250 gp range for most of the levels that most play happens in, I use an average of 150 gp here for a facility use, but there certainly are large error margins.
With that warning out of the way, the expected value of a reroll on the event table is about 75 gp. As you are spending 500 gp to make that reroll, the expected net effect is more than 400 gp loss.
Clearly, from a purely materialistic perspective, this is not worth it, and it gets even worse when you are high level and your facility actions are worth more. So it is really for the narrative, less quantifyable benefits that you would take the opportunity. As @minmass says in this answer, a DM may plan for consequences of either humoring and honoring, or rebuffing a powerful spellcaster or domineering noble.
Here are the details on my take on the value of each event. The overall value is the weighted sum of those (I used 0 for the reroll, which I think is close enough; you could calculate the weights again without that event, but the guesstimated values have so much error margin, I did not think it is worth doing).



d100
Event
Prob
Description
gp impact
Comment




1-50
All is Well
50%

0



51-55
Attack
5%
Roll 6d6, for each 1, lose a defender. If zero defenders, random facility shuts down for next turn; then is repaired
-150
Assumes no defenders. If you have any, expected losses are not going to catch up with your ability to restock


56-58
Criminal Hireling
3%
Pay d6 x 100 gp [-350] or loose hireling, if facilty has none, shuts down for a turn, and they are replaced.
-150
Depends on facility - usually at 150 gp it will be less than the bribe cost, so you are better off not paying.


59-63
Opportuntiy
5%
Pay 500, gain renknown and reroll.
n/a
This event cannot happen on the reroll.


64-72
Friendly Vistors
9%
d6*100 gp
350



73-76
Guest
4%
25% each: mark of reknown, d6*100 gp, +1 defender, monster negating attack losses 1x then leaves
87.5
counting the gp from the cash out chance


77-79
Lost Hirelings
3%
lose hirelings for one facitly one turn
-150
estimated average value


80-83
Magical Discovery
4%
uncommon potion or scroll
225
uncommen scrolls are level 2 or 3 and worth on average 250 gp, uncommon potions are worth 400/2 (as consumable)


84-91
Refugees
8%
d6*100 gp
350



92-98
Request for Aid
7%
roll d6 per defender vs 10 total for d6x100gp or 1/2 and losing one defender
175
assume you do not do it if not at least 50/50 chance, then either full or half payout


99-00
Treasure
2%
roll on art object table
280
average weighted result


Total

100%

73





1 In my estimation, a use of a random facility is worth about 50 gp initially, althought this varies widely by facilty, and it is lower in the lower levels, and goes up in the higher levels, where it can be worth up to several thousand gp.
First, it depends on you being able to make use of some of the items that can be produced. If you can, then you get the full worth. If you cannot, then you'll likely end up selling them to monetize for half price, and as they cost half price in materials, you'd make no money. I assume you craft things you would otherwise buy, so you get value out of them.
Second, some effects like charms or information do not map to a gp value in a straightforward way. I used the value for purchasing spellcasting services from the PHB p. 232 to estimate the gp value for spells or charms that emulate them, although that may be overestimating their practical value somewhat. I did not put a value on getting new information, as I had no rational way to value that.
The facilities that allow for crafting use the normal rules, and can be run by the hirelings instead of you (unless you want a magic item that can cast spells), so they save you precious downtime you otherwise would need to spend on crafting. For mundane items, you can craft 10 gp price worth per person day (70 in a week, the duration of a normal faction turn), half cost for material, so this generates 35 gp per week and hireling. For those facilities that can craft magic items, uncommon ones have a value of 400 gp, cost 200 material to craft, for a value gain of 200, and take 10 person-days to craft. As you only have 7 days per normal turn, the value surplus per turn is 7/10 x 200, or 140 per hireling. For spell scrolls, it takes 5 days to scribe a level 3 one worth 300 gp, the best gp value per day of work, again for a surplus of half that, or 150 gp. So you can craft 7/5 x 150 gp of profit per turn and hireling, or 210 gp.
Here is the table, the colums titled lvl give the expected gp values:



Type
Game Effect
lvl 5
lvl 9
lvl 13
lvl 17
Upgrade/Comment




Arcane Study
1x Identify charm up to 7 days. Craft Arcane focus, blank book (10 gp), lvl 9+: arcane common/uncommon magic item; must be present and know spells for those
70
190
190
190



Armory
Add weapons 100 gp + 100 gp/defender - half if Smithy. Defenders roll d8 instead d6, then need to restock
-25
-25
-25
-25
Minium 1 defender, but likely at least 4 for -500 gp, only need to restock every ~20 turns


Barrack
House up to 12. Recurit: add up to 4 Defenders
0
0
0
0
Host up to 25


Garden
Flower: 10 bouquets [50], 10x Perfume [50], 10 Candles [0.1]; Food: 100 rations [50]; Herb: 10 Healer's Kit [50] or Potion of Healing [50]; Poison: 2 Antitoxin [100], 1 basic poison [100]
100
100
100
100
Double capacity (can be different garden type), 1 more hireling


Library
Three accurate pieces of information previously unknown to you.
0
0
0
0



Sanctuary
1x Healing Word charm, 7d. Craft Sacred or Druidic focus
60
60
60
60
Lvl 1 spell, focus is 10 gp


Smithy
Craft anything with Smiths Tools (Metal Weapons, med & heavy armor, Ball bearings, bucket, caltrops, chain, crowbar, bullets, grappling hook, pot, spikes
70
140
140
140
If level 9+, craft common/uncommon Armament item


Storehouse
Buy up to 500/2,000(9th)/5,000(13th) gp of goods, can sell them at 10%/20%/50%/100% more at level 5,9,13,17
50
400
2,500
5,000



Workshop
Heroic Inspiration for short rest per day. Six of Carpenter, Cobbler, Glassblower, Jeweler, Leatherworker, Mason, Painter, Potter, Tinker, Weaver, Woodcarver tools. Craft: Can craft anything the tools can make using normal rules. If level 9+, craft common/uncommon Implement.
105
420
420
420
Upgrade 2 more hirelings, 3 more tools. EV +70 gp (+280gp level 9+).


Gaming Hall
Gambling, roll d100: 10 gp x 0-50 d6, 51-85 2d6, 86-95 4d6, 96-00 10d6; avg 73.5 gp

73.5
73.5
73.5



Greenhouse
Potion of Healing, greater [200], Poison: Assassin's Blood, Malice, Pale Tincture, Truth Serum [150-250], 3 x Lesser Restoration/day, usable 24h

850
850
850



Laboratory
Anything that can be made with Alchemist Supplies (Acid, Alch Fire, Comp Pouch, Oil. Paper, Perfume [50]; Poison (Burnt Othor Fumes, Essence of Ether, Torpor) [600]

600
600
600



Sacristy
Craft free Holy Water (can pay 100gp up to 5x to increase dmg by d8 each). Common or uncommon Relic magic item; once per long rest regain level 5 or lower spell by short rest in here

140
140
140



Scriptorium
Replicate a book (need a blank book). Craft Spell Scroll of level <=3 spell; or 50 copies of a pamphlet, cost 1gp/ea distribute to places within 50 mi

210
210
210



Stable
Can have multiples. Has one Riding Horse, Camel, or 2 Pony, Mule. Can house 3 large, or 2 med in place of 1 large. Beasts who spend at least 14 days gain Adv on Animal Handling.  Buy at normal cost, sell at 20% margin (50% at lvl 13, 100% at 17)

45
112.5
225
Can house 6 large


Teleportation Circle
Act as target for teleportation circle spells. 50% of spellcaster, who casts lvl 4 spell (lvl 8 if you are 17+); must pay materials. stays 14 days or until spell cast, does not defend bastion

2,000
2,000
20,000



Theater
14d prep, 7 d+ performance. can contribute as writer/director/performer. DC 15 Performance, if group check wins, all gain a d6/d8/d10 (level 9/13/17) to add to a d20 Test result at any time once (immediately after d20 roll). can have only one

0
0
0



Training Area
Choose: Battle - Reaction to reduce strike dmg suffered by d4; Skills - proficiency in 1 of Acrob, Athlet, Perf, Slight, Sttealth; Tools - prof in tool; Unarmed - unarmed strikes deal extra d4, Weapon - gain prof, or if prof, mastery. Need to train 8h for 7 days to benefit, lasts for 7 days

0
0
0



Trophy Room
Three accurate pieces of information previously unknown to you. Or 50% to get a random common Implement magic item.

25
25
25



Archive
Legend Lore effect. Arcana, History, Investigation, Nature, Religion check Adv if in here


2,000
2,000
Vast: 2 more ref books


Meditation Chamber
Roll 2x on Bastion events, and choose, instead 1x- After 7 days, gain Adv on 2 random saves


0
0



Menagerie
Up to 4 Large (4 med/small take space as 1 large), Recruit Beast or Monstrosity, who can count as bastion defenders, up to CR3. (1/8 50 Hyena, Jackal, 1/4 250 Panther Constrictor-Snake, 1/2 500 Croc Ape Black-Bear, 1 1000 Brown-Bear Dire-Wolf Tiger Giant-Vulture Lion, 2 2000 (none given), 3 3500 Owlbear)


0
0



Observatory
Contact other Plane charm. 50% chance of charm of Heroism, Darkvision, Vitality


2,000
2,000



Pub
Location of any familiar creature if in 50 mi after 7 days unless hidden. One of Enlarge, Spider Climb, Darkvision, Necrotic resistance, auto-save vs Frightened for 24h for all drinkers.


800
800
2 options for the drink, 3 more hirelings


Reliquary
Greater Restoration charm for 7d after long rest. One-time replacement for component worth <=1000 gp [1000]


3,000
3,000



Demiplane
Fabricate mundane item <5 gp <5ft each dim. per long rest.. 5x= thp for long rest within, 7 days



5



Guildhall
Adventurer: capture or slay CR <=2 Beast for Tropyh Room, Menagerie; Baker: bread or favor [500]; Brewer: fifty 40-gallon ale barrels [400]; Mason: defensive wall takes 1 day/5ft instead of 10; Shipbuilder: build ship, you pay full cost; Thieves': steal nonmagical item <= 5 ft each dim within 50 mi



500



Sanctum
1x heal charm for 7d, thp = your level for beneficiary on long rest (works remote). Word of Recall always prepared, if to sanctum one creature of choise gets heal



20,000



War Room
2 Veteran Warriors "Lieutenents", do not count as defenders, but lower number of lost by 1 pip. Recruit: Add one Lieutenant, up to 10. Or raise army of 100 Guards per Lieutenant or 20 on Riding Horses. Cost you 1 gp to feed each/day. Can only have one army.



0



Average Value

48
275
608
1942





Nice, thanks for the analysis. It’s  really good. I wonder if Crawford signed off on this.

The incentive lies in the first paragraph of the description of the "Extraordinary Opportunity" entry:

Your Bastion is given the opportunity to host an important festival or celebration, fund the research of a powerful spellcaster, or appease a domineering noble. Work with the DM to determine the details.

If you roll "Extraordinary Opportunity" and pay the 500 gp to seize the opportunity, something happens (eg., hosting an important festival), and you roll again on the table to see what else happens during that turn.
This GM would work with the player to determine the broad strokes of the opportunity before the players need to decide whether to seize it and work out the finer details after the decision had been made (I infer that from the wording in the entry, plus I think it makes sense to do it that way in-world).
I also believe that the decision of whether or not to seize the opportunity should have some echoing consequences (though not necessarily mechanical or immediate ones - that's largely what the second roll is for). For example: the spellcaster whose research you aid may return the favor with a key piece of information later, or the appeased noble might be more easily persuaded to help the party out of a bind.
So: in a role-playing game, your character/party gets to decide whether to spend some coin to do something "cool" and unique. The decision doesn't necessarily have an immediate in-game pay-off but, with a good GM, could - I daresay "should" - have consequences later on.
... plus, you get to roll again on the table and hope for something more immediately-tangible.

Just to clarify, the GM is at liberty to make this a detriment at whim, right? You say the something should be a benefit. But, nothing says it has to be.

@nonymous: yes, but no. The consequences should flow from the choice and the event. Agreeing to help a wizard research a version of prestidigitation that allows for cleaning whole houses instead of just a single item probably shouldn't result in the torches-and-pitchforks brigade showing up.

Perhaps, though it could result in e.g. an explosive reaction. The DMG could use a few more tables to determine what might be a commensurate cost and benefit/detriment for risking the Extraordinary Opportunity at a given level. But, as written, it seems pretty lazy. I guess I wanted to know if there was more to it. Regardless, as is, the cost seems totally superfluous to the whole process.

Great answer showcasing the power of role playing beyond the pure mechanics of the game!
